# Does using data from another website increase their SEO?

Tags: seo, xml

To clarify, if I wear to use xml data from another website to make charts on my site, would that affect their SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't affect their SEO as it is not on their website nor are you linking to their website. The most that can happen is if the content produced from that data creates a page that closes matches their page then it will be flagged as duplicate content and the newer page, your page, will be filtered out of the search results. It is possible that their page may be filtered out as Google is still working on getting better at who the content originated with, but that will continue to improve over time and you should generally consider that your page will be the one filtered out.

Comment: Also thanks for the possible case description as well.